# How to listen queue different virtual hosts?

Tags: spring-amqp

I need to connect multiple virtual hosts at the same time because I want to listen to queues in multiple hosts. Configuration-based mode only creates one connection by default. How can I create multiple connections? How do I specify a different connection factory when registering listeners with annotations?

```
spring.rabbitmq.host=10.0.0.0
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=test
spring.rabbitmq.password=test
spring.rabbitmq.virtual-host=ABC
```

How do you specify a connection factory in multiple registered listeners?

```
@RabbitListener(queues = Constants.QUEUE_NAME)
    public void receiveMessage(Test message) {
        System.out.println("Received <" + message.getA() + ">");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is currently no way to do it with just properties. You have to define multiple `CachingConnectionFactory` `@Bean`s and multiple listener container factory beans, each one pointing to each connection factory.

Or, you can use a `RoutingConnectionFactory` [as described in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/#routing-connection-factory) which can be configured to use a particular connection factory based on the listener queue name(s).

We have an [open issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues/891) to add support for auto-config of multiple factories.

The author has [a project that might help you](https://github.com/mytaxi/spring-multirabbit).

If you go with multiple container factories...

The `@RabbitListener` annotation has this option:

```
/**
 * The bean name of the {@link org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.RabbitListenerContainerFactory}
 * to use to create the message listener container responsible to serve this endpoint.
 * <p>If not specified, the default container factory is used, if any.
 * @return the {@link org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.RabbitListenerContainerFactory}
 * bean name.
 */
String containerFactory() default "";
```

So, you can declare a bean for the `RabbitListenerContainerFactory` and inject there any custom `ConnectionFactory`:

```
/**
 * @param connectionFactory The connection factory.
 * @see AbstractMessageListenerContainer#setConnectionFactory(ConnectionFactory)
 */
public void setConnectionFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
```

That's indeed the case that only one `virtual host` per connection factory:

```
/**
 * Set the virtual host.
 * @param virtualHost the virtual host to use when connecting to the broker
 */
public void setVirtualHost(String virtualHost) {
```

See more info about a custom `containerFactory` in Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.1.4.RELEASE/reference/#using-container-factories

Comment: Looks like the open issue was solved, can you update the answer?